# Redirection with play! 2 scala after a post with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, scala, post, playframework-2.0

So far I used the usual method to post a form and redirect to the page I wanted to display like this :

The `HTML` part :

```
<form name="createArtistForm" method="post" action="/admin/createArtist">
    Nom de l'artiste : <input type="text" name="artistName">
    <input type="submit" value="Valider"/>
</form>
```

And the `Scala` part :

```
val artistBindingForm = Form(mapping(
    "artistName" -> nonEmptyText(2)
  )(Artist.formApply)(Artist.formUnapply)
  )

def createArtist = Action { implicit request =>
    artistBindingForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(formWithErrors.errorsAsJson),
      artist => {
        artistId = Artist.saveArtist(artist)
        Redirect(routes.ArtistController.artist(artistId))
      }
    )
  }
```

And it worked fine, but now, the front end part of my app is managed by AngularJs so I submit the form with its http service like this :

```
$http.post('/admin/createArtist', {artistName : $scope.artiste.name})
```

The new artist is still well saved in my database, but the redirection has no effect.

What should I do in order to make the redirection work ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use to do in this cases is receive the result of the operation (error or success) and in case of success, redirect on the front end side with js (location = url).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can you explain me how I should transmit the artist Id (that depends of my database) from the server to the frond end in order to display the artist that I just created?

Comment: I finally found a solution : instead of making the redirection on the client side, I return to the client side a Json response and I redirect on the proper page with angualrJs.